# Find forgotten password in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, passwords

Is there to way to find forgotten password in `Jenkins ver. 2.60.1` by having  access to the server?

Please do not suggest to disable security and reset password. I need to find the forgotten password.

Answer (score 1):

The password is AES128 encrypted and the key is stored locally. Not sure why you wont just reset the password instead. So a little apprehensive about the goal. Reverse engineer it.

Comment: <passwordhash>overlaying key</passwordhash>

Comment: Thanks. Don't worry, I asked this question just for my information and will try to decrypt.

Comment: Are you sure it's encrypted and not hashed?